# Make Regex match to the first occurance

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
*asdasda**asdasdaSD*
```

And I want to split it into 2 half

```
*asdasda*
*asdasdaSD*
```

I'm unsure of how to do this in Regex. This is my current one `\*.+\*`, but it will match from the start to the end. How can I make it only match the first one it finds?

Comment: Perhaps `\*[^*]+\*`?

Comment: @Nick good idea. I have just tried that but for some reasons, it doesn't match the second bit.

Comment: how silly me ==". I forget to turn the global flag on

Comment: Do you want to Split this string into multiple lines or into an array?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
let answer = '*asdasda**asdasdaSD*'.match(/\*[^*]{1,}\*/g);
// answer[0] equals *asdasda*
```

Thanks!